# Zip File Corrupted App created by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zip, wear-os

I have develop an app for a smartwatch (wearOs) that creates a zip. The app writes data on a Txt, and when it finishes doing the tasks it has to do, it compresses the Txt creating a Zip.

In most of the smartwatch in which I have installed the app, it works without problems. But, in other, I get corrupted Zips.

In this cases, sometimes it lets me decompress without problems and in others I get an error (0x80004005).

The way that I zip the Txt file is:

```
private File zip(File[] files){
        File zipFile = null;
        try {
            sendHandlerMessage(0, COMPRESS_STATE);

            // Compress data block and write compressed data in temporal compressed file
            zipFile = new File(files[0].getParentFile(),files[0].getName().replace("txt","zip"));
            ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile)));

            executorZipService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(files.length);
            for(int i = 0; i< files.length; i++){
                int finalI = i;
                executorZipService.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
                        try {
                            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[finalI].getName());
                            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(files[finalI]);

                            int count;
                            long fileSize, actualSize=0;
                            fileSize = files[finalI].length();

                            while ((count = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                                actualSize=actualSize+count;
                                sendHandlerMessage((int) Math.ceil((actualSize/fileSize)*100),COMPRESS_STATE);
                                //Log.d("CUSTOM_TAG",""+ i++);
                            }

                            fileInputStream.close();
                            files[finalI].delete();
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            executorZipService.shutdown();
            executorZipService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            zipOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //sendInfoToMainActivity(Constants.SENDING_STATE);
        SystemClock.sleep(10);
        return zipFile;
    }
```

I don't know what I need to change. On some watches it works without problems and on others it doesn't, so I don't know why.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? You don't use `try-with-resources` and you don't close the streams in `finally` blocks. Any exception that happens will leave the zip stream unclosed and this corrupts it.

Comment: It looks like you are zip-ing multiple files to one single file in parallel. ZipOutputStream is not designed to work that way. Simple fix is to change to Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)

Comment: @marcinj theoretically it only has to compress 1 txt, but I left it like this because if there is any error and there is any txt from past processes, I saved them in the same zip file.

Comment: @Chaosfire I didn´t see any exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **create a ZIP** file in Android Studio using Java,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Specify the source directory and the name of the output ZIP file
        String sourceDirectory = "/path/to/source_directory";
        String zipFileName = "/path/to/output.zip";

        // Call the createZipFile method to create the ZIP file
        createZipFile(sourceDirectory, zipFileName);
    }

    public static void createZipFile(String sourceDirectory, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            File source = new File(sourceDirectory);
            File zipFile = new File(zipFileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            zipDirectory(source, source, zos);

            zos.close();
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("ZIP file created successfully: " + zipFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void zipDirectory(File source, File basePath, ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
        File[] files = source.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    zipDirectory(file, basePath, zos);
                } else {
                    String entryName = file.getPath().substring(basePath.getPath().length() + 1);
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName);

                    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    fis.close();
                    zos.closeEntry();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to replace /path/to/source_directory with the path to the directory you want to zip and /path/to/output.zip with the desired output ZIP file's path and name.

This code defines a ZipCreator class with a createZipFile method that creates a ZIP file from a source directory and its subdirectories. The zipDirectory method is used to recursively traverse the source directory and add files to the ZIP. The ZIP file is created using java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.

**Hope it helps**